LiveData is not updating its value on 2nd api call
I am fetching currency exchange rate by api call using retrofit and ViewModel concept.On launch of application I am able to get the latest data from the server but when I am trying to update the live data by clicking the button, Live Data value is not updating, I am getting the same old data.So can anyone please help me out how to update live Data on button click event.
ViewModel Class*****
class MainViewModel(private val repository: CurrencyRepository) : ViewModel() {
init {
    viewModelScope.launch() {
        repository.getCurrencyExchangeList()
    }
}

val quotes: LiveData<CurrencyData>
    get() = repository.currencyLiveData

}
Repository Class*****
class CurrencyRepository(private val currencyService: CurrencyInterface) {
val currencyLiveData = MutableLiveData<CurrencyData>()


suspend fun getCurrencyExchangeList() {
    val result = currencyService.getAllCurrencyData()
    if (result.body() != null) {
        //currencyLiveData.postValue(result.body())
        currencyLiveData.value = result.body()
    }
}

}
Method(in MainActivity) to get and update currency list *****
private fun fetchCurrencyRates() {
    val currencyService = RetrofitHelper.getInstance().create(CurrencyInterface::class.java)
    val repository = CurrencyRepository(currencyService)
    val mainViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this, MainViewModelFactory(repository))[MainViewModel::class.java]
    mainViewModel.quotes.observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d("AllCurrencyList", it.updated)

    })

}


Is fetchCurrencyRates the method being called when a button is clicked? If so, why are you creating the viewmodel and everything else in it?

In your ViewModel's init function you call the repository's getCurrencyExchangeList
This code will be executed only 1 time, when the ViewModel is created.
When do you want to trigger the update? through a button click?
In that case add a public method in the ViewModel that calls repository.getCurrencyExchangeList()
And as @tomerpacific pointed out, you need to initialise the ViewModel once and then reuse it throughout the activity.
